# Why fstream doesn't work with excel.csv

Tags: c++, excel, csv, fstream

I am trying to add data into excel with fstream but csv doesnt work, I don't know if I am doing something wrong. Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open("test.csv");
    file << "one,two" << endl;
    file << "three" << " , " << "four\n";
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

the results are one,two in the cell A1 and three,four int the cell B1
Edit: expected A1 = one A2 = two B1 = three and B2 = four

Comment: Did `open` work? You should check that with e.g. `if(file.is_open())`

Comment: It has to be open because I have the data in it, just not in different cells

Comment: Can you spell out "something wrong" in that case. What is the file contents afterwards? What do you expect? Do check file operations have actually worked though, as good habit.

Comment: If you are in a non-english locale, where `','` is the decimal separator, you might want to try `';'` as the field separator.

Comment: Sounds more like you are having issues **importing** the CSV, rather than writing it. It seems to be fine, on disk. But you are instructing the application to not interpret "," as the field delimiter. You need to fix your import procedure; writing the file is fine.

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot, how do I close the threat?